# Переход на https и смена домена

Tags: https, домен

Стоит 2 задачи: сменить домен с .com.ua на .ua и перейти на https. 
Вопрос: в каком порядке проводить две операции, возможно ли оптимизировать процессы и решить их одновременно.
Спасибо!

Comment: так как сертификат получается на доменное имя, то логично будет получить его сразу на новый домен. И да, конечно можно это делать одновременно. причем оставив оба домена на переходный период, старый на http, новый уже с https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Регистрируете новый домен
2. Настраиваете http версию сайта на новом домене, поскольку компания, выпускающая сертификат, обычно проверяет принадлежность домена, запрашивая некую информацию по этому адресу
3. Получаете сертификат.
4. Настраиваете https-версию сайта
5. По старому и новому http адресу настраиваете 301 редирект на новый https-адрес (чтобы поисковики и пользователи по сохраненным старым ссылкам перешли на новый https адрес)
6. В панели google и yandex webmsters (если были) настраиваете новый https-адрес. Поисковики считают http и https разными адресами

Если у вас уже есть новый домен, и есть быстрый способ получения сертификата (например LetsEncrypt), то все действия можно сделать одновременно. Времени займет пару часов. Но могут быть простои при перезапусках веб-сервера. Так что лучше делать в моменты наименьшей загрузки